# Column does not exist in the IN clause, but SQL runs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that uses the `IN` clause.  Here's a simplified version:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table A
  JOIN table B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
 WHERE B.AnotherColumn IN (SELECT Column FROM tableC WHERE ID = 1)
```

`tableC` doesn't have a `Column` column, but the query executes just fine with no error message.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: This should give you an error *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.*

Comment: @astander: I agree, it should give an error, but it doesn't

Comment: Sorry, I meant if the Actual Column name was 'Column'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will work if a table in the *outer* query has a column of that name. This is because column names from the outer query are available to the subquery, and you could be deliberately meaning to select an outer query column in your subquery SELECT list.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #test_main (colA integer) 
CREATE TABLE #test_sub (colB integer)

-- Works, because colA is available to the sub-query from the outer query. However,
-- it's probably not what you intended to do:
SELECT * FROM #test_main WHERE colA IN (SELECT colA FROM #test_sub)

-- Doesn't work, because colC is nowhere in either query
SELECT * FROM #test_main WHERE colA IN (SELECT colC FROM #test_sub)
```

As Damien observes, the safest way to protect yourself from this none-too-obvious "gotcha" is to get into the habit of qualifying your column names in the subquery:

```
-- Doesn't work, because colA is not in table #test_sub, so at least you get
-- notified that what you were trying to do doesn't make sense.
SELECT * FROM #test_main WHERE colA IN (SELECT #test_sub.colA FROM #test_sub)
```

Comment: You have got to love Correlated Subqueries. Useful in many areas and causing grief for those who don't know: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: @Stephen Heck, I've known about this gotcha for more than a decade, and it still trips me up every now and again. I think I was probably first to answer because I did it yet again last week... At least with long experience it's normally a quick "D'oh!" followed by a fix, rather than two hours of puzzling over why I'm not getting any results!

Comment: @Matt Gibson: One thing that hasn't been cleared up, is what exactly is the `OUTER` query retrieving?

Comment: @Ardman Well, in my first example, if there are ten rows in #test_main, and no rows in #test_sub, then no rows will be retrieved from the overall query. However, if you put a row in #test_sub -- containing *anything* -- then you'll get all ten #test_main rows back from the overall query. Consider a row where #test_main.colA has the value 5. Effectively your query reduces to `SELECT * FROM #test_main WHERE 5 IN (SELECT 5 FROM #test_sub)`. This pattern will hold for every row, so as long as there's anything at all in #test_sub, you'll get back all the rows from #test_main. Get it?

Comment: @Matt Gibson: Excellent.  Thanks.  But, as you see in my example, I have a `WHERE` clause so how does this effect things?  Is it saying: `SELECT (first value from table B) FROM tableC WHERE ID = 1)`?

Comment: @Ardman No, it *really is* saying `(SELECT Column FROM tableC WHERE ID = 1)`, just like it says. As Column isn't present in tableC, for your query to be syntactically correct (ignoring the confusing fact that Column is a keyword!), then Column must exist in either A or B. Let's say it's A. Your query then boils down to `...WHERE B.AnotherColumn IN (SELECT A.Column FROM tableC WHERE ID = 1)` So, for every row in your main query, you'll get a match, and therefore a row returned, if B.AnotherColumn equals A.Column, but only if there are any rows in tableC where ID = 1.

Comment: @Ardman No worries! If it helps, try thinking about queries like `SELECT 'aardvark' FROM t WHERE id = 1` -- this is the kind of thing that's going on with your subquery. You'll just get as many rows containing the word 'aardvark' back as there are rows in t where id = 1. Once you realise what's happening with the subquery, I have a feeling a light will go off in your head :)

Comment: So it will also get the first matching value from table A (for example)?

Comment: @Ardman This may be a good time to take a break from the problem and have a drink :)

Comment: I did that and thought it through.  Its sunk in :o)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ardman No problem! I'm sure someone helped me through this at some point; it's one of the weirder bits of SQL, especially when you trip over it for the first time...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid this situation in the future (that Matt Gibson has explained), it's worth getting into the habit of always using aliases to specify columns. E.g.:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table A
  JOIN table B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
 WHERE B.AnotherColumn IN (SELECT C.Column FROM tableC C WHERE C.ID = 1)
```

This would have given you a nice error message (note I also specified the alias in the where clause - if there wasn't an ID column in tableC, you'd have also had additional problems)