# Why does this SQL code does not generate an error?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Column does not exist in the IN clause, but SQL runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076906/column-does-not-exist-in-the-in-clause-but-sql-runs)

I stumbled upon this today while at work today and I was wondering, why is it that the following code does not generate and error?

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (ColumnA VARCHAR(25))
CREATE TABLE #TableB (ColumnB VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO #TableA (ColumnA) VALUES('1')
INSERT INTO #TableA (ColumnA) VALUES('2')
INSERT INTO #TableA (ColumnA) VALUES('3')

INSERT INTO #TableB (ColumnB) VALUES('1')

SELECT *
FROM #TableA
WHERE ColumnA IN(SELECT ColumnA FROM #TableB)
```

**Output:**

```
ColumnA
1
2
3
```

ColumnA does not exists on #TableB, how come no error is generated?

@@VERSION tells me I'm running this in:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)
```

Comment: use alias `SELECT *
FROM #TableA A
WHERE A.ColumnA IN(SELECT B.ColumnA FROM #TableB B)` and check errors

Comment: Already answered, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076906/column-does-not-exist-in-the-in-clause-but-sql-runs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ColumnA` in the subquery `(SELECT ColumnA FROM #TableB)`
 refers to the `ColumnA` of #TableA which is a valid column in SELECT list.

Hence there's no error and you get three rows since you are comparing the #TableA.ColumnA with #TableA.ColumnA

If you want to verify the above statement replace ColumnA with anything but other than a valid column (e.g ColumnAB) you will get an error.

If you try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (ColumnA VARCHAR(25))
CREATE TABLE #TableB (ColumnB VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO #TableA (ColumnA) VALUES('1')
INSERT INTO #TableA (ColumnA) VALUES('2')
INSERT INTO #TableA (ColumnA) VALUES('3')

INSERT INTO #TableB (ColumnB) VALUES('1')

SELECT *
FROM #TableA
WHERE ColumnA IN(SELECT ColumnAB FROM #TableB)
```

the output will be

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Invalid column name 'ColumnAB'.

Comment: Very nice. Another way to explain it is there is obviously no error in `SELECT * FROM #TableA WHERE ColumnA IN (SELECT 42 FROM #TableB)`. In the context of the subquery, ColumnA, like 42, is defined, if not the answer to everything.

Comment: I feel dumb! You are 100% correct, I've done this many times it's just that I'm used to using the columns from the outer query in the WHERE clause of the inner query. 
For example:
`SELECT *
FROM #Table t
WHERE t.Id IN(SELECT MAX(tIn.Id)
               FROM #Table tIn
               WHERE tIn.Column = t.Column)`
    
For some odd reason I saw this differently.